# How to prove that a series of random variables $Z_j = 1$ or $-1$ occurring at risk-neutral probability, converges to normal, using the CLT?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, binomial-tree, lognormal, risk-neutral

### Context

When pricing options with trees, it is convenient to prove that the asset value at expiry $S_t$ be of log-normal distribution:

$$\log{S_t} = \log{S_0} + \mu T + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{T}{n}} \sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j$$

where $\mu$ is the mean of the asset value (drift), $\sigma$ its standard deviation (volatility), $T$ is the time to expiry and $n$ the number of steps $\Delta t = T/n$ in the tree.

Last term $\sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j$ assumes values $Z_j = 1$ or $-1$ with risk-neutral probability $p_{RN}$

$$p_{RN} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+ \left( \frac{r - \mu - 0.5 \sigma^2}{\sigma} \right) \sqrt{\Delta t} \right) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t)$$

Term $\sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j$ has mean $\nu$

$$\nu = n \left( \frac{r - \mu - 0.5 \sigma^2}{\sigma} \right) \sqrt{\Delta t} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t)$$

and variance $$1 - \nu^2 = n + \mathcal{O}(1)$$.

Having computed these two quantities, the book I am following hastens to declare that the Central Limit Theorem applies to $\sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j$, which to me is not immediate to see since its mean and variance are not $0$ and $1$.
Then the author proclaims that this allows to prove that $\log{S_T}$ converges to a log-normal distribution:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \log{S_T} = \log{S_0} + \left( r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) T + \sigma \sqrt{T} N(0,1)$$

and thereafter proceeds to derive the Black-Scholes formula.

### Question

How to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j - \nu}{\sqrt{(1-\nu^2)}} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j}{\sqrt{n}} = N(0,1)$$ as prescribed by the Central Limit Theorem, holds?
(for further clarity, here $N(0,1)$ is the normal distribution, while $n$ is the number of time-steps in the tree)

### EDIT

I had overlooked the fact that mean $\nu$ and variance $1 - \nu^2$ are already defined with respect to the whole sum $\sum_{j=1}^{n} Z_j$, and not just to the single r.v. $Z_j$.

$n$ is already inside the mean and variance definitions, so I have taken it out of terms in the CLT expression (in last equation).

Still, mean $\nu$ directly depends on $n \sqrt{\Delta t} = \sqrt{Tn}$, so for $n \to \infty$, $\nu$ goes to $\infty$, not to $0$ as it would need in order to validate the application of CLT.

Comment: Hi: What you wrote at the end after "how to prove that" is the CLT for the sample sum of an RV which is a re-write of the CLT for the sample mean. So, you are already there as far as I can tell. Of course, this assumes that you have the mean and the variance correct and I didn't read that part so disclaimer there.

Comment: This looks reasonable as far as an explanation. https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter9.pdf

Comment: @markleeds my question should then be rephrased as 'how is it possible to manipulate the first equation, for it to yield the last equation in the 'Context' section of my question, using formulas in between and the CLT ?' What troubles me is the Normal distribution popping up in the last term of the lim of $\log S_T$

Comment: if mean and variance of $\sum Z_j$ were 0 and 1 this would be self-evident, but they are equal to $\nu$ and $1 - \nu^2$, generally different from 0 and 1, so should not be so straightforward to plug the $N(0,1)$ distribution in the last term of the lim of $\log{S_T}$.

Comment: Hi Lingo: I don't have time right now but I'll look at it late tonight because I must have mis-understood your question. Printing out and will try to read on my travels today.

Comment: Thank you @markleeds , please excuse my labouring the point too much... I have made a new edit to the last equation. Essentially what I am asking is how is the author allowed to substitute $N(0,1)$ to $\sum_{j} Z_j / \sqrt{n}$ in the $\log{S_T}$ expression, given that mean and variance of that sum are not 0 and 1, so CLT doesn't immediately apply? ...Lucky you, still able to travel :).

Comment: okay. thanks. I'm printing it out again since you edited it. will read today but of course I can't guarantee an answer. Assuming I can't answer, it might be a good question to ask on cross validated but first let me see if I can make any progress. Of course, any one else is welcomed to also.

Comment: Yet some new insight, I wrote a new EDIT section. No need to print again though. Now all that remains to prove is that $\nu \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$, but I cannot see how he did it. Probably playing around with the big-O notation.

Comment: Lingo: I don't know how to show it mathematically, but, intuitively, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\triangle t \rightarrow 0$ because the time step gets narrower and narrower as $n$ increases. So, the multiplication I think goes to zero because $T$ is fixed. But maybe someone else can show it more rigorously.

Comment: True what you say, that would stand if there were no $n$ in the numerator of $\nu$, yielding something $\propto \sqrt{n}$. I think it cancels out with the $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator, but the latter is not of higher order, so should yield 1 and not 0! 0 would be required to prove normality...

Comment: I see what you're saying. the other confusion I had is, if $Z_i$ only takes values of 1 and -1 and the probability of these is the same, then how can the expectation be non-zero ? Is the expectation not taken with respect to the risk neutral measure ? Thanks and apologies that I can't be of more help.

Comment: I know it is tricky! He is considering interest rates so the expectation will be $E[S_T] = S_0 e^{rT}$ and so in general $p_{RN} \neq 0.5$. The book is *Concepts and Practice of Mathematical Finance* by M. Joshi, chapter 3 pages 63-64. 

In any case, thank you for spending time on this, I can feel I have gained a better grasp of this chapter now, even though this issue remains unanswered.

Comment: Thanks Lingo. That explains the strangeness about the expectation. As far as your question, I would suggest that you email Dr. Joshi but, unfortunately, he died a few years ago unexpectedly. A very kind and generous person based on various things about him that I've seen on the net. As far as travel, I just meant the bus and train ( in NYC ), Not anywhere far !!!!! I'll keep the problem in my bag so I can look at it when the urge arises. All the best.

Comment: Lingo: Just one other thing.  I don't have it here with me but, if you can get your hands on Cox and Rubenstein's "option pricing",  that might provide some insight as far as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Obviously,  as $ n \rightarrow \infty$, the  steps, $\triangle t$ are shrinking in width so that the discrete price is becoming continuous. I'm guessing that C&R might have something useful to say about this phenomena.

Comment: @markleeds The article you cite is in fact the primary reference to the "incriminated" chapter of the book, by admission of the author himself in the final notes of it. But I left this aside for the moment, and trudged forward to the next chapter.

Comment: Ok. No problem. It's been a looooooooooooooooooong time but I remember C&R being really useful when I was trying to understand options for the first time. Maybe, when you get a chance to look at it, it will be helpful.